# Fragmentation behavior of spots in TLC

Tags: organic-chemistry, chromatography, purification

I tested multiple development using eluent condition hexane + 1% of ethyl acetate. Then I observed kind of fragmentation of spot.

[image: Multiple development]

I'm not sure, but I guess that successive spots are from the skyblue spot in the bottom. What is the cause of this phenomenon? I know there can be a tailing when the concentration is too high, but this seems somewhat different from the tailing.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by fragramentation of a spot? This is not classical tailing. Are you thinking that those blue spots are all of the same compound? This is quite unlikely. How many compounds were expected?

Comment: @AChem I expect that there is about 6 compounds, but I can't explain those if the blue spots are all different compounds. As I continue multiple development, blue spots successively locates at the same positions. Are there chances that this behavior is observed when dealing with amine compounds? Even, if I use more polar eluent system then another color of 'fragmentation' is observed.

Comment: I think, they are all different but closely related compounds and that is the same fluorophore is present in each (beautiful blue!). One compound will not show this "spotted" behaviour.

Comment: You may try using another solvent system as well to develop the TLC. One solvent system cannot tell us anything. Another more advanced trick is to use two-dimensional TLC.

Comment: @AChem Guess I'd better try 2D TLC... Thank you.

Comment: 2D TLC might be very telling. Your compound could be decomposing (silica is a Lewis Acid, and wet silica is a Bronsted acid).

Comment: @BenNorris Oh, I missed the possibility of decomposition. Thank you. I would try it.